# Can inductive sensors work on anodized aluminum?

Tags: inductive, industrial, aluminium

I was wondering if an industrial-grade inductive sensor can detect an **anodized aluminum** plate. From what I know, based on the working principle of these sensors (basically the metal is detected by its own magnetic field thanks to Eddy current) I suppose the sensor would have a hard time detecting the anodized surface, but I'm not sure.

Kindly let me know based on your experience or knowledge regarding the topic. Thanks in advance!

P.D.: In case you ask about the specific type of anodizing, for this case let us consider a simple Type-II anodizing, with a thickness no greater than 0.4 mils.

Answer (score 3):

The thin layer of anodization will not really affect the performance of the inductive sensor in any way.

No more than air, paint or any other non-conductive material between the sensor and the metal.
The sensor will not detect the anodization in itself, but it will still detect the aluminium that is behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will implement a couple of inductive sensor on my application :)